# One part of my web app shows only sometimes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, ecmascript-6

I am developing my first web app for learning purposes. It consists on a calendar wher you can add tasks, edit, and remove them asynchronously. Simple.

Everything seemed to work fine but once I uploaded it to my hosting, one friend reported me he can´t see the calendar, only the header and the footer... he says it happens on all browsers, but that on the smartphone it works fine... I checked myself and I can see it fine on all my browsers (that´s why I have not noticed), but happens the same bug on smartphone! It is just the same problem my friend had, but on the opposite device.

I contacted the hosting, and changed the PHP version to the most similar I had on the XAMPP I used to develop it... (5.6.32 on xampp and 5.6.35 on the hosting), but the problem still goes on.

I also tried to update bootstrap version. Calendar is done with bootstrap, JS (with some ES6 features like importing-exporting modules) and jquery returning data through PHP from a database... nothing special.

Do you know what could be happening? To see the calendar you must be logged.

If you want to log and see it, use these fake credentials:

email: test@gmail.com
pass: 12345678

and this is the link

http://myreminder.avanzartewebs.com/

I will put the head tag of the problematic file to see if it can give you a hint

```
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" defer></script> 

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->

    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>

    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-lZmvU/TzxoIQIOD9yQDEpvxp6wEU32Fy0ckUgOH4EIlMOCdR823rg4+3gWRwnX1M" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/styles.css">

    <script src="getAndPrintDate.js" defer></script>

    <!--<script src="assets/js/crearCalendario.js" defer></script>-->
    <script src="view_crearAnioCompleto.js" type="module"></script>

    <!--<script src="assets/js/buildList.js" defer></script>-->

    <!--the scripts with type=module (which work with modules using the imports) are defer by default-->
    <script src="../controls/clickOnCell.js" type ="module" ></script>
    <script src="../controls/taskSubmit.js" type ="module" ></script>
    <script src="../controls/listButtonsClick.js" defer ></script>
    <script src="../controls/editTaskSubmit.js" type="module" ></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/fontawesome-all.js" defer ></script>







</head>
```

Comment: I'm unable to replicate the problem. When I log in I see the calendar on all browsers and my iPhone X.

Comment: I will try to use a version without ES6 import/export to see if that fixes it. Don´t know what could be causing it

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading those instead of having them linked from their site and try that. My the host is blocking it. Thats something i would try just to see.

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-lZmvU/TzxoIQIOD9yQDEpvxp6wEU32Fy0ckUgOH4EIlMOCdR823rg4+3gWRwnX1M" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>
```

Comment: ok will try, on the smartphone on private browser shows right, but not on normal one

Comment: ok, downloaded and changed:  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" >  

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" defer></script>

Comment: can you check now please?